# Can we update the Projection of existing Global Secondary index of a DynamoDB table?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-dynamodb-index

Can we update the Projection of existing Global Secondary index of a DynamoDB table ?

I want to update the projection to ALL so save the redundant call to partition key.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there is not a way to update the projection.

If it was me, I'd create a new GSI with the new projection, switch the code to use the new one, then delete the old GSI.

Comment: Thanks @Kirk, I was about to do the same thing! Thanks a lot!!